# Произвольный цикл на Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, вёрстка, woocommerce

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, как создать на главной странице магазина вывод товаров разных категорий, но с разным оформлением блоков, в которых находятся товары?
Т.е. в боковой колонке допустим будет вывод самых продаваемых товаров и чуть ниже товары распродажи. В центральной части страницы будут выводиться товары разных категорий. И в вёрстке предусмотрено так, что каждая из перечисленных выше категорий оформлена по разному: некоторые категории с анимацией, некоторые находятся в слайдере по несколько товаров в ряд, некоторые в слайдере, но слайдер в боковой колонке в один ряд, некоторые без анимации и т.д.
Как правильно организовать вывод всех товаров на главной странице с разным оформлением?
Это нужно делать произвольный цикл? Как тогда определять в цикле допустим самые продаваемые товары, или товары распродажи, и как для них назначить правильно определённые стили с нужными блоками?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас 35 вопросов в одном, но постараюсь ответить в общих чертах.

Прежде чем забираться в дебри произвольных циклов по товарам, стоит использовать шорткоды.

Для самых продаваемых товаров:

```
[best_selling_products per_page="12"]
```

Товары распродажи:

```
[sale_products per_page="12"]
```

Разных категорий:

```
[product_category category="appliances, phones"]
```

Оберните эти шорткоды в дивы типа `<div id="best_products">...</div>` и задайте свои css правила для каждого id.

Подробнее о всех шорткодах WooCommerce можно почитать в официальной документации [здесь](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/).

Comment: Оберните эти шорткоды в дивы типа <div id="best_products">...</div> и задайте свои css правила для каждого id.

Comment: И никаких проблем - все так работают. В любом случае поправить css в разы проще, чем делать собственный цикл woocommerce.

Comment: Допустим в шаблоне есть такой код:
<?php echo do_shortcode('[product_category category="computers-laptops"]'); ?>
во 1х шорткод добавит ненужные классы, что-то типа 
'class="woocommerce columns-4"'
обернёт в свои блоки.

Comment: И допустим в файле content-product.php я делаю проверку, которая заключается в определении того, откуда вызывается данный файл: 'if(is_page_template('content-main.php')){' 'if ($woocommerce_loop['name'] == 'product_cat') { ?>' но эта проверка не срабатывает почему-то. Т.е. файл content-main.php является шаблоном для главной страницы

Comment: Извиняюсь за оформление, 1й раз на сайте

Comment: `И допустим в файле content-product.php я делаю проверку` - это уже новый вопрос, который надо оформлять отдельно, согласно правилам StackOverflow. Так установлено для того, чтобы ответы потом можно было найти через поисковики.

Comment: хорошо, что мне делать с теми ненужными классами и блоками, которые вставляет код шорткода?
Эти новые блоки ломают вёрстку

Comment: эти блоки не являются ненужными, и правильную верстку не ломают. Я неоднократно делал сайты с шорткодами WooCommerce.

Comment: это образно сказано, что они ненужные, т.е. в данном случае они ломают вёрстку. В другом случае они возможно и пригодятся, если вёрстка не сильно наворочена.
Как избавиться от этих блоков ?

Comment: Так что вы посоветуете, немного переделать вёрстку с этими новыми блоками и классами, такими как woocommerce columns-4 ?

Comment: Я посоветую подогнать свою верстку под WooCommerce или воспользоваться их стандартной темой или любой другой совместимой

Comment: Кстати в шаблоне content-main.php вызывается такой шорткод, приведённый выше: <?php echo do_shortcode('[product_category category="computers-laptops"]'); ?> Я посмотрел метод класса WC_Shortcodes, который отвечает за этот шорткод product_category. В этом коде метода product_category не должно возвращаться дополнительных блоков, таких как woocommerce columns-4. Они возвращаются только из метода product_categories, т.е. из метода категорий во множественном числе. Почему так происходит, почему возвращаются эти новые блоки?

Comment: Потому что разработчики решили оформить форматирование вывода для нескольких категорий по-другому.